# 2D matrix beyond certain size won't run in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to make a very simple diffusion plus flow simulation for the purpose of learning C. (flow will be added later with superpositioning.)
But when I increase the size of my matrix (2D array), I get:

*** Process returned -1073741571 ***

I don't think the returned value means anything, but whatever the (too large) size of my matrix is, it returns the same value. (google gave no results on this specific value)
It seems I can increase the size to 207 x 207 without any problems, but anything larger will result in the same returned value. (and no CSV file written)

First I thought it had something to do with a value being out of bounds. But I can't find the error and when I run it with smaller matrices the code is working fine.

An other option I could think of was the amount of maximum memory used by my IDE (Pelles C 9.00.9) But a google search gave no results of that.

I know that currently the code is poorly optimized (I'm still figuring out how pointers work and there is some other things as well) But I can't imagine the problem lies in that.

If someone could point me to what I can do to work with larger matrices, it would be highly appreciated.

Below is the code I'm currently working on. As it is, it works, however when constants V or DT are reduced, the matrix size is increased and it no longer works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

/*
This scrip will create a grid in which a starting position is given of partial pressure of a gas.
Using forward Euler on Fick's law, it will calculate the state after given time.
Define parameters here: */
#define TMAX 1.0 /*simulation time (s)*/
#define DT 0.01 /*time step (s)*/
#define L 0.10 /*Length of environment (m)*/
#define T 0.10 /*Thickness of environment (m)*/
#define V 0.05 /*Velocity of the gas (m/s)*/

/*Define gas parameters here:*/
#define D 0.1 /*Diffusivity (cm2/s)*/
#define M 32 /*Molar mass (g/mol)*/
#define C 0.01 /*starting concentration (mol/L)*/
double d = D*10000; /*Diffusivity (m2/s)*/
double size = V*DT; /*Determine grid size based on velocity and time steps*/

/*Define filename for output*/
#define FILENAME "test.txt"


/*For this simulation it is assumed that the diffused gass is in a closed environment with atmospheric
pressure air at 298K
In addition, it can only simulate diffusion from left to right and top to bottom*/


void writematrix(char str[], double mat[10][10]){
  
  FILE * fp;
  fp = fopen (str, "w+");
  int i;
  int j;
  int Ni = L/size; /*Number of location steps in length*/
  int Nj = T/size; /*Number of location steps in thickness*/
  for(i=0;i<Ni;i++){
    for(j=0;j<Nj;j++){
      fprintf(fp, "%e",mat[i][j]);
      if(j<Nj-1){
        fprintf(fp,";");
      }
    }
    fprintf(fp,"\n");
  }
  printf("csv file is writen as:\n");
  printf(str);
  printf("\n");
}

int main(){

  /*Define starting situation (all zeros exept for location [0,0]*/
  int Ni = L/size; /*Number of location steps in length*/
  int Nj = T/size; /*Number of location steps in thickness*/
  printf("Current grid is: %d x %d\n",Ni,Nj);
  double grid[Ni][Nj]; /*Define grid*/
  int i;
  int j;
  for(i=0;i<Ni;i++){
    for(j=0;j<Nj;j++){
      grid[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
  grid[0][0] = C*size*size*size; /*Start situation*/
  double t;
  double diffL[Ni-1][Nj];
  double diffT[Ni][Nj-1];

  /*Loop over all time steps*/
  for(t=0.0;t<=TMAX;t += DT){

  /*Calculate the particle flux in L direction*/
    for(i=0;i<Ni-1;i++){
      for(j=0;j<Nj;j++){
        diffL[i][j] = (grid[i+1][j] - grid[i][j])/size;
      }
    }

  /*Calculate the particle flux in T direction*/
    for(i=0;i<Ni;i++){
      for(j=0;j<Nj-1;j++){
        diffT[i][j] = (grid[i][j+1] - grid[i][j])/size;
      }
    }

  /*Add flow to current situation*/
    for(i=0;i<Ni-1;i++){
      for(j=0;j<Nj;j++){
        grid[i][j] += size*size*DT*d*diffL[i][j];
        grid[i+1][j] -= size*size*DT*d*diffL[i][j];
      }
    }
    for(i=0;i<Ni;i++){
      for(j=0;j<Nj-1;j++){
        grid[i][j] += size*size*DT*d*diffT[i][j];
        grid[i][j+1] -= size*size*DT*d*diffT[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  /*Convert grid to mol/L*/
  for(i=0;i<Ni;i++){
    for(j=0;j<Nj;j++){
      grid[i][j] = grid[i][j]/(size*size*size);
    }
  }


  writematrix(FILENAME,grid);
  

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: The stack is typically only a few megabytes. So declaring large arrays as local variables is a bad idea (local variables go on the stack). The arrays (like `grid` and `diffL`) either need to be global variables, or declared with the `static` keyword. Note that the size of the `grid` array is 207*207*8 = 343KB. `diffL` and `diffT` are about the same size, so that puts you over 1MB.

Comment: `writematrix` gets a 10x10 matrix, so won't work with NixNj